# Que jeito posso validar hora corrente

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Como poderia desenvolver rotina [bloco de código], afim de tratar o campo de texto onde deve-se inserir as Horas em tempo real (Horário vigente, decorrente no momento). Caso o usuário tente adicionar horas passada - emitir aviso que não pode inserir horário utrapassado do **dia**.

## Por exemplo:

Se agora são *7:00* da manhã, o usuário poderá colocar as *7:00, 7:01* ou 7:02 ou **mais**, mas nunca.. introduzir **menos**.

Isso evita que o(s) usuário(s) *malicioso e/ou desavisado* tente burlar o sistema - então soará um:

`alert('Horário inaceitável. Você atrasou seu danadinho! Insira a HORA atual. Quando chegar o dia do pagamento a gente conversar.rsrs')`

## Código

```js
function Mascara_Hora(Hora){ 
 var hora01 = ''; 
 hora01 = hora01 + Hora; 
   if (hora01.length == 2){ 
  hora01 = hora01 + ':'; 
  document.forms[0].Hora.value = hora01; 
   } 
  if (hora01.length == 5){ 
    Verifica_Hora(); 
  } 
   } 
   
 function Verifica_Hora(){ 
 hrs = (document.forms[0].Hora.value.substring(0,2)); 
 min = (document.forms[0].Hora.value.substring(3,5)); 
       
 estado = ""; 
 if ((hrs < 00 ) || (hrs > 23) || ( min < 00) ||( min > 59)){ 
   estado = "errada"; 
 } 
       
 if (document.forms[0].Hora.value == "") { 
   estado = "errada"; 
 } 
 
 if (estado == "errada") { 
   alert("Hora inválida!"); 
   document.forms[0].Hora.focus(); 
   } 
 }
```

```html
<input name="Hora" type="text" id="Hora" class="input_text" OnKeyUp="Mascara_Hora(this.value)" size="5" maxlength="5">
```

---

Contudo quase pronto só resta esta lógica [aceitar hora atual pra validar], que ainda não sei.

Comment: Então o correto é validar ao lado do servidor também, porque se o usuário desabilitar o *JavaScript* no navegador já era.

Comment: @wmsouza Na verdade o que tô querendo é um exemplo, mas isso será feito do lado do server mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de seu método, crie variáveis para armazenar a hora e minuto atual.

```
var hora = new Date().getHours();
var minuto = new Date().getMinutes();
```

Depois altere sua condição para verificar se `hrs` é menor que `hora`, e se `min` é menor que `minuto`:

```
if ((hrs < hora ) || (hrs > 23) || ( min < minuto) ||( min > 59)){ 
  estado = "errada";
}
```

#### Exemplo funcionando:

```js
function Mascara_Hora(Hora){
  var hora01 = ''; 
  hora01 = hora01 + Hora; 
  if (hora01.length == 2){ 
    hora01 = hora01 + ':'; 
    document.forms[0].Hora.value = hora01; 
  } 
  if (hora01.length == 5){ 
    Verifica_Hora(); 
  } 
} 

function Verifica_Hora(){
  var hora = new Date().getHours();
  var minuto = new Date().getMinutes();

  hrs = (document.forms[0].Hora.value.substring(0,2)); 
  min = (document.forms[0].Hora.value.substring(3,5)); 

  estado = ""; 
  if ((hrs < hora ) || (hrs > 23) || ( min < minuto) ||( min > 59)){ 
    estado = "errada";
    // Altera o valor do campo com a hora atual
    document.forms[0].Hora.value = hora + ':' + minuto;
  } 

  if (document.forms[0].Hora.value == "") { 
    estado = "errada"; 
  } 

  if (estado == "errada") { 
    alert("Hora inválida!"); 
    document.forms[0].Hora.focus(); 
  } 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="Hora" type="text" id="Hora" class="input_text" OnKeyUp="Mascara_Hora(this.value)" size="5" maxlength="5">
</form>
```